# Table view section heigh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have an table view with 4 sections and 1 row in each section.Is there a way to make the row of the first section bigger than the other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can change the frame of the cell before you return it in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

so it is larger. Just add something like

```
UITableViewCell * cell = ...
// ...
if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
    // change the frame of the cell
}
// ...
return cell;
```

Comment: i Use awakeformnib and there i set the heigh how do i get the section in that method? thanks

Comment: i used this method heightForRowAtIndexPath thanks for the help

Comment: I'm happy I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following method (implementing from `UITableViewDelegate`)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 100; // the desired height
    }
    else
    {
        return 44; // or whatever your default cell height is
    }
}
```

*edit*: misread your question. Do as Warkst suggested.